# webrtc configration return null value

Tags: webrtc

I am implementing webrtc for peerconnection but not working. when i debug this code then i saw it is not coming in

```
    theirConnection.onaddstream = function (e) {
        theirVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
    };
```

block. please let me know where i have done wrong? I am using this on my local system and with one webcam only.

```
function startPeerConnection(stream) {

    var configuration = {
        "iceServers": [{ "url": "stun:127.0.0.1:8080" }]
    };

    yourConnection = new mozRTCPeerConnection(configuration);
    theirConnection = new mozRTCPeerConnection(configuration);
    // Setup stream listening

    theirConnection.onaddstream = function (e) {
        theirVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
    };


    // Setup ice handling
    yourConnection.onicecandidate = function (event) {
        if (event.candidate) {
            theirConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
        }

    };

    theirConnection.onicecandidate = function (event) {
        if (event.candidate) {
            yourConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
        }
    };

    // Begin the offer
    yourConnection.createOffer(function (offer) {
        yourConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
        theirConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);

        theirConnection.createAnswer(function (offer) {
            theirConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
            yourConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the promise methods. The problem is literally that you're not checking for errors.

**Specifically:** The [legacy callback methods](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#legacy-interface-extensions) you seek expect at least two arguments: a success callback, *and* a failure callback.

Without a failure callback, WebIDL name-overloading calls the [newer promise methods](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#interface-definition) instead, which take no callbacks and return a promise instead.

Either pass in the required error callbacks everywhere, e.g.:

```
yourConnection.createOffer(offer => { ... }, err => console.log(err));
```

Or better, avoid the legacy methods altogether:

```js
function startPeerConnection(stream) {

  var config = { iceServers: [{ urls: "stun:127.0.0.1:8080" }] };

  yours = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
  theirs = new RTCPeerConnection(config);

  theirs.onaddstream = e => theirVideo.srcObject = e.stream;
  yours.onicecandidate = e => theirs.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
  theirs.onicecandidate = e => yours.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);

  yours.addStream(stream); // <-- don't forget

  return yours.createOffer()
    .then(offer => Promise.all([yours.setLocalDescription(offer),
                                theirs.setRemoteDescription(offer)]))
    .then(() => theirs.createAnswer())
    .then(answer => Promise.all([theirs.setLocalDescription(answer),
                                 yours.setRemoteDescription(answer)]));
}
          
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})
  .then(stream => startPeerConnection(stream))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

```html
<video id="theirVideo" height="120" width="160" autoplay></video>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

And always check for errors. A `createOffer` error told me you'd forgotten `.addStream(stream)`.

The promise API is available natively in Firefox, and through [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) in Chrome.